# GameObject optimization in backpack behavior

Tags: unity, software-engineering, inventory

I am trying to design the item part of my game. My original design was just to treat them as a gameobject and to give every item an `item` (or some derived) component, and when the item was picked up, such an item would join into the backpack as an invisible gameobject (attached to the `backpack` UI canvas). Then, when moving the items to the chest or some storages, it also moves the gameobject itself. However, I believe this approach is inconvenient and will be resource-consuming to some extent.

Are there any designs that could optimize the item to be purely scripted data structure?
Is it common to do so? I haven't researched too many open-source games, but when I took the game design course, I did so as I described.

I was looking for an approach like:

- be able to link the image of the item (just like the gameobject does).
- minimizing the cost when adding or moving/removing the item from the bag

My most desired outcomes are like the bag in the MonsterHunter.

I just need some ideas to get work done.

Comment: You may be interested in [How to store Unity component after destroying GameObject](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/168620/39518). The key point: the collectible pickup object on the ground, the object owned in your inventory, and the thing you spawn when you equip/move the object *don't all have to be the same object*. They just need to *reference* some item ID, and that item ID can have the name/image/whatever you need associated with it, without all the overhead of being a full-fledged game object with a mesh or collider, etc. Ordinary object pooling can let you recycle the pickups.

Comment: Making it a scriptableObject sounds like a good idea, in fact, I did use something similar on other parts, why didn't I think about that? Anyway, I will try to do more research and give it a try, thank you!

Comment: It as well depends on your items. Scriptable Objects won't really work when your items have a range of stats that are random

Comment: @Zibelas it can if you have a deterministic RNG and you save your item as an {archetype, seed} pair. Then you can reconstruct an identical instance of the random item's parent type on demand when needed.

Comment: So if I have an item as a scriptableobject, should the `amount` attribute be bound with the the item or maintained by some inventory? Because I think if I simply change the amount of some item, it will change everything that references to it.